# cURL POST Spring Security with CSRF enabled

Tags: java, curl, spring-security, nullpointerexception, csrf-protection

I want to use cURL for HTTP `POST` request with CSRF enabled, but always I get the same error. Here my code:

**Spring Security configuration:**

```java
http
    .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(new Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint())
        .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/cim/**").hasRole("USER")
        .and()
    .formLogin()
        .passwordParameter("password")
        .usernameParameter("username")
        .loginProcessingUrl("/cim/login")
        .failureHandler(authFailHandler)
        .successHandler(authSuccessHandler)
        .and()
    .logout()
        .logoutUrl("/cim/logout")
        .and()
    .addFilterAfter(new XSRFHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
```

**cURL call:**

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"type": "journey","descriptif": "rmrmrmrmr","hash":"KQJ4pj6Vy6SL99ynkNnjcGRkwr5eAwceakxbAE8xH5lvno1ZDJcW4RamRmwMuqx7pBXqvpHa8n5lMKjLHr8p","name":"shop_achat_2015-09-15_2015-09-15rmrmr","user": "admin"}' http://localhost:8080/cim/explore/form
```

**Error:**

```
<p>Problem accessing /cim/explore/form. Reason:
<pre>    Server Error</pre></p><h3>Caused by:</h3><pre>java.lang.NullPointerException
    at fr.aid.cim.web.security.audit.MultiReadHttpServletRequest.getValueParameter(MultiReadHttpServletRequest.java:140)
    at fr.aid.cim.web.security.audit.MultiReadHttpServletRequest.getParameter(MultiReadHttpServletRequest.java:86)
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getParameter(ServletRequestWrapper.java:194)
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getParameter(ServletRequestWrapper.java:194)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1699)
    at fr.aid.cim.web.security.audit.RequestWrapperFilter.doFilter(RequestWrapperFilter.java:27)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1691)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:523)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**XSRFHeaderFilter.java**

```
public class XSRFHeaderFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    public static final String XSRF_TOKEN = "XSRF-TOKEN";

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
        if (csrf != null) {
            Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, XSRF_TOKEN);
            String token = csrf.getToken();
            if (cookie==null || token!=null && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
                cookie = new Cookie(XSRF_TOKEN, token);
                cookie.setPath("/");
                response.addCookie(cookie);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

**Note:**
the problem is with csrf i can't fix it because when i add csrf().disable() in the Springconfig that works well but i want to enable csrf

Comment: yes that works with mhen i use CSRF: curl   --cookie "JSESSIONID=ls5ofdv63jufy40bhc5v9tih" -H "X-CSRF-Token: 5c66782d-4060-4fa4-81d3-60a11a111b2c" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"type": "journey","descriptif": "cpeoeoe","hash":"KQJ","name":"shop_achat_2015-09-15_2015-09-15rmrmr","user": "admin"}' http://localhost:8080/cim/explore/form     But the problem now that i test with csrf and cookie genrated with login page in chrome network but i want to get the csrf and cookie with curl login and that generated the same problem with csrf.enabled()

Comment: Super but the login method is generated by Spring security i can't update it to GET:loginProcessingUrl("/cim/login")  I test with this curl :                       curl -v -i -H "Content-type: application/json" -c cookies.txt -X GET -d "username=admin&password=admin" http://localhost:8080/cim/login but i can't authentify to my application(with this curl i get sessionid and csrf but not working)

Comment: First you have to load your login page to get CSRF and session token (with HTTP `GET`), second you have to authenticate yourself with username/password, CSRF token and session  token (with HTTP `POST`). You can't do it with one request.

Comment: Thanks that helps me